# How do I use jquery autosuggest to redirect to another url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, autocomplete, autosuggest

So I've been scouring the internet for a solution that I thought was going to be common and easy, but it seems that all the links I've browsed upon are either more than what I need or they just glaze over the parts I need and want to understand.

I'm developing a site where I would like to have a field where users can type in a state, it will autosuggest possible states and when a user selects a state it will redirect the page to another url. So: if they select "Alaska, AK" they get directed to "http://.../states/alaska"

From all that I've searched through, the [jquery UI autosuggest remote source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote), seems to be the closest to what I need.  I liked that I wasn't needing to go through a database, the values are in the "search.php" file.

In the search.php file the values are inserted as:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
if (!$q) return;
$items = array(
"Great Bittern"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
"Little Grebe"=>"Tachybaptus ruficollis",
"Black-necked Grebe"=>"Podiceps nigricollis",
"Little Bittern"=>"Ixobrychus minutus",
...
```

I've tested that I can change the values here to:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
if (!$q) return;
$items = array(
"Alabama, AL"=>"http://.../states/alabama",
"Alaksa, AK"=>"http://.../states/alaska",
"Arizona, AZ"=>"http://.../states/arizona",
...
```

In the HTML the code is:

```
$(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
    });
```

I don't need it to show a log, how do I reformat this to get the page to redirect when selected or when the user hits the submit button?

Comment: by the way it seems like there's a lot of related files that need to be attached in order for this to work, so if anyone has anything smaller, do tell.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use one of these

```
window.location.href = "new link";
```

or

```
window.location.replace("new link");
```

Maybe like this

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    window.location.href = ui.item.value :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
```

Comment: well that worked. Thanks.  Now that I'm putting this together into production I'm realizing that it's taking 9 linking files and 41kb to make this whole thing come together. Seems a little extreme. Does anyone have any alternatives?

Comment: If you have say 9 different answers you can put them in database and then create a div in your page where you load the result based on the user selection. This needs some ajax however.

Comment: I was looking at those types of scripts.  My issue was that they all were pulling in only one value for the suggestion text and ID. I didn't need the ID, I needed the suggestion text and URL field. Problem is that I don't know MySQL/JSON/AJAX syntax at all so figuring out how to modify was impossible for me and there was no beginner level documentation of the scripts.